# Maximize number of inversion count in array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures

We are given an unsorted array `A` of integers (duplicates allowed) with size `N` possibly large. We can count the number of pairs with indices `i < j`, for which `A[i] < A[j]`, let's call this `X`.

We can change maximum one element from the array with a cost equal to the difference in absolute values (for instance, if we replace element on index `k` with the new number `K`, the cost `Y` is `| A[k] - K |`).
We can only replace this element with other elements found in the array.

We want to find the minimum possible value of `X + Y`.

Some examples:

- [1,2,2] should return 1 (change the 1 to 2 such that the array becomes [2,2,2])
- [2,2,3] should return 1 (change the 3 to 2)
- [2,1,1] should return 0 (because no changes are necessary)
- [1,2,3,4] should return 6 (this is already the minimum possible value)
- [4,4,5,5] should return 3 (this can accomplished by changing the first 4 into a 5 or the last 5 in a 4)

The number of pairs can be found with a naive `O(n²)` solution, here in Python:

```
def calc_x(arr):
    n = len(arr)
    cnt = 0
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i+1, n):
            if arr[j] > arr[i]:
                cnt += 1    
    return cnt
```

A brute-force solution is easily written as for example:

```
def f(arr):
    best_val = calc_x(arr)
    used = set(arr)
    for i, v in enumerate(arr):
        for replacement in used:
            if replacement == v:
                continue

            arr2 = arr[0:i] + replacement + arr[i:]

            y = abs(replacement - v)
            x = calc_x(arr2)

            best_val = min(best_val, x + y)
    return best_val
```

We can count for each element the number of items right of it larger than itself in `O(n*log(n))` using for instance an AVL-tree or some variation on merge sort. 
However, we still have to search which element to change and what improvement it can achieve.

This was given as an interview question and I would like some hints or insights as how to solve this problem efficiently (data structures or algorithm).

Answer (score 0):

Definitely go for a O(n log n) complexity when counting inversions.

We can see that when you change a value at index k, you can either:

1) increase it, and then possibly reduce the number of inversions with elements bigger than k, but increase the number of inversions with elements smaller than k

2) decrease it (the opposite thing happens)

Let's try not to count x every time you change a value. What do you need to know?

In case 1):

You have to know how many elements on the left are smaller than your new value v and how many elements on the right are bigger than your value. You can pretty easily check that in O (n). So what is your x now? You can count it with the following formula:

```
prev_val - your previous value
prev_x - x that you've counted at the beginning of your program
prev_l - number of elements on the left smaller than prev_val
prev_r - number of elements on the right bigger than prev_val
v - new value
l - number of elements on the right smaller than v
r - number of elements on the right bigger than v

new_x = prev_x + r + l - prev_l - prev_r
```

In the second case you pretty much do the opposite thing.

Right now you get something like O( n^3 ) instead of O (n^3 log n), which is probably still bad. Unfortunately that's all what I came up for now. I'll definitely tell you if I come up with sth better.

EDIT: What about memory limit? Is there any? If not, you can just for each element in the array make two sets with elements before and after the current one. Then you can find the amount of smaller/bigger in O (log n), making your time complexity O (n^2 log n).

EDIT 2: We can also try to check, what element would be the best to change to a value v, for every possible value v. You can make then two sets and add/erase elements from them while checking for every element, making the time complexity O(n^2 log n) without using too much space. So the algorithm would be:

1) determine every value v that you can change any element, calculate x

2) for each possible value v:

- make two sets, push all elements into the second one
- for each element e in array:
  add previous element (if there's any) to the first set and erase element e from the second set, then count number of bigger/smaller elements in set 1 and 2 and calculate new x

EDIT 3: Instead of making two sets, you could go with prefix sum for a value. That's O (n^2) already, but I think we can go even better than this.